# Centering Text in SwiftUI Pie Chart and Adjusting Opacity for Selection

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm working with SwiftUI to create a pie chart using `SectorMark` in a `Chart` view. I have two challenges:

1. I'm struggling to center text in the middle of the pie chart. The text should display the selected token's balance, but it's not aligning correctly in the center.
2. I want to set a low opacity for all sectors and then highlight the selected sector by changing its opacity to a brighter color.
   Any suggestions on how to center the text properly and adjust the sector opacity for selection would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
struct TokenAllocationChartView: View {
    let tokenHolders: [Token]
    @Binding var selectedBalance: Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Chart(tokenHolders) { tokenHolder in
                SectorMark(
                    angle: .value("Balance", Int(tokenHolder.balance)!),
                    innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
                    angularInset: 1.5
                )
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Names", tokenHolder.name))
            }
            .chartAngleSelection(value: $selectedBalance)
         
            .frame(height: 300)
            
            VStack(alignment:.center) {
                Text("Token Allocation")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                
                Text(String(selectedBalance ?? 0.0))
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve your two issues thanks to a similar test app I had.
Here's the code:

```
let tokens: [Token] = [
    .init(name: "Mat", balance: "2000"),
    .init(name: "Jon", balance: "5000"),
    .init(name: "Fred", balance: "1200"),
    .init(name: "Tom", balance: "950"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedBalance: Double? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TokenAllocationChartView(
            tokenHolders: tokens,
            selectedBalance: $selectedBalance)
    }
    
}

struct TokenAllocationChartView: View {
    let tokenHolders: [Token]
    @Binding var selectedBalance: Double?
    @State private var barSelection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Chart(tokenHolders) { tokenHolder in
                SectorMark(
                    angle: .value("Balance", Int(tokenHolder.balance)!),
                    innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
                    angularInset: 1.5
                )
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Names", tokenHolder.name))
                .opacity(barSelection == nil ? 1 : (barSelection! == tokenHolder.name ? 1 : 0.4))
            }
            .chartAngleSelection(value: $selectedBalance)
            .chartXSelection(value: $barSelection)
            
            .frame(height: 300)
            
            VStack(alignment:.center) {
                Text("Token Allocation")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    .frame(height: 0) // <-- Add this line for center perfectly
                    
                
                Text(String(selectedBalance ?? 0.0))
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedBalance, initial: false) { oldValue, newValue in
            if let newValue {
                findToken(newValue)
            } else {
                barSelection = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func findToken(_ rangeValue: Double) {
        var initalValue: Double = 0
        let convertedArray = tokens.compactMap { token -> (String, Range<Double>) in
            let rangeEnd = initalValue + (Double(token.balance) ?? .zero)
            let tuple = (token.name, initalValue..<rangeEnd)
            /// Updating inital value for next iteration
            initalValue = rangeEnd
            return tuple
        }
        
        /// Find the value in the range
        if let token = convertedArray.first(where: { $0.1.contains(rangeValue) }) {
            /// Update selection
            barSelection = token.0
        }
    }
}

struct Token: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var balance: String
}
```

The key part is the findToken function which takes in the current double value selected and finds the correct token name whose that fits that value.
For higlighting the pie chart the opacity modifer is just what we need, and to center the Text inside the chart you just need the height to the Token Allocation text and set maxHeight for the enclosing VStack. The Result: [image: Selecting Pie Chart]

Comment: Thank you so much friend. Just one question, what is your approach to state management ? Specifically how do you keep track of the selection ?

Comment: I use the barSelection variabile to modify the opacity as you can see, and barSelection varies thanks to the onChange modifier that listens to changes of selectedBalance. When barSelection is equal to a token name (that is determined in the findToken function) the relative pie chart bar gets selected, or the others turns off, better said.